# How to scan BigQuery table with DLP looking for sensitive data?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dlp

I would like to analyze my tables in **BigQuery** using **DLP**. It is possible ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible. You need to define your storage_config to use BigQuery.
If you want to save findings in another table, then add a `save_findings` action to the job config. Without actions you will only have access to the job's finding summary via the `projects.dlpJobs.get` method.

**Follow the example in python to invoke DLP to scan BigQuery:**

```
client_dlp = dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient.from_service_account_json(JSON_FILE_NAME)

inspect_job_data = {
    'storage_config': {
        'big_query_options': {
            'table_reference': {
                'project_id': GCP_PROJECT_ID,
                'dataset_id': DATASET_ID,
                'table_id': TABLE_ID
            },
            'rows_limit':10000,
            'sample_method':'RANDOM_START',
        },
    },
    'inspect_config': {
        'info_types': [
            {'name': 'ALL_BASIC'},
        ],
    },
    'actions': [
        {
            'save_findings': {
                'output_config':{
                    'table':{
                        'project_id': GCP_PROJECT_ID,
                        'dataset_id': DATASET_ID,
                        'table_id': '{}_DLP'.format(TABLE_ID)
                    }
                }

            },
        },
    ]
}
operation = client_dlp.create_dlp_job(parent=client_dlp.project_path(GCP_PROJECT_ID), inspect_job=inspect_job_data)
```

**And a query to analyze  the result:**

```
client_bq = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(JSON_FILE_NAME)
# Perform a query.
QUERY = (
    'WITH result AS ('
    'SELECT'
    ' c1.info_type.name,'
    ' c1.likelihood,'
    ' content_locations.record_location.record_key.big_query_key.table_reference as bq,'
    ' content_locations.record_location.field_id as column '
    'FROM '
    ' `'+ GCP_PROJECT_ID +'.'+  DATASET_ID +'.'+  TABLE_ID  +'_DLP` as c1 '
    'CROSS JOIN UNNEST(c1.location.content_locations) AS content_locations '
    'WHERE c1.likelihood in (\'LIKELY\',\'VERY_LIKELY\'))'
    'SELECT r.name as info_type, r.likelihood, r.bq.project_id, r.bq.dataset_id,'
    ' r.bq.table_id, r.column.name, count(*) as count  FROM result r GROUP By 1,2,3,4,5,6 '
    'ORDER By COUNT DESC'
)
query_job = client_bq.query(QUERY)  # API request
rows = query_job.result() 
for row in rows:
    print('RULES: {} ({}) | COLUMN: {}.{}.{}:{} | count->{}'.format
          (row.info_type, row.likelihood, row.project_id,row.dataset_id,row.table_id,row.name, row.count)
```

You can find more details [here](https://medium.com/@kanjihara/scanning-bigquery-table-with-google-cloud-data-loss-prevention-dlp-996e4ceb175f)

Answer (score 0):

A community tutorial has been published talking about your use case: [dlp-to-datacatalog-tags](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/dlp-to-datacatalog-tags).

Following it you are able to run DLP in all your Big Query resources, and automatically create Tags in Google Data Catalog.

So you are able to search for sensitive information, using Google Data Catalog search syntax.